# How to override the CSS of TinyMCE dropdown

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, tinymce

I have integrated tinyMCE editor into my Vue.js Application.

```
init = {
      height: 500,
      menubar: false,
      plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
        'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount',
        'image imagetools',
      ],
      toolbar:
        'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | image code | help',
    }
```

The issue is whenever I click in the options of the TinyMCE Editor say Paragaph the options list is going down and not coming like a dropdown.
[image]

I tried using the class of the paragraph option and overriding the CSS written in it but somehow it is picking the default CSS. Is there a way to override the CSS of the options in the TinyMCE Editor?

#. Update
I am able to override the CSS

```
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 534.828px;
    top: 312.203px;
    max-height: 341px;
    overflow: hidden auto;
    min-width: 130px;
}
```

by adding the media query to it

```
 .tox .tox-menu.tox-collection.tox-collection--list {
    top: -38rem !important;
    left: 39rem !important;
  }
```

Is there a better way to do without writing media queries?

Comment: Did you inspected the DOM with your devtools? Can be handy to find out what are the classes used.

Comment: @kissu yess I did and tried to override the style in  .tox-menu tox-collection tox-collection--list tox-selected-menu  but somehow it is taking the default CSS only\

Comment: Probably need an `!important` to override it.

Comment: @kissu yess added that as well

Comment: Probably a scope or specificity issue. Do you have a [repro]?

Comment: @kissu I have added a new update to this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a media query but a CSS selector. And if the plugin does not provide a specific way to inject styles, using `!important` is totally fine.

At the end, it's basically overriding default styles.